# Get ClientCertificate in OAuth WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, x509certificate2

I'm developing a WebApi and I want to send an `X509Certificate2` when I get the token to validate the user.

I use the task of `LoadClientCertAsync` but I can't find the certificate.

Here is my code

```
GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
        var loadClientCertAsync = (Func<Task>)context.Request.Environment["ssl.LoadClientCertAsync"];
        await loadClientCertAsync();
```

Thank you